# How do I access NancyFX Request Header values

Tags: http-headers, nancy

I need to get some custom (shibboleth) header values out the `Request.Headers` collection. Currently I am managing to do this using the following code:

```
CommonName = Request.Headers["cn"].FirstOrDefault();
Email = Request.Headers["mail"].FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a less cumbersome syntax to get at the header values? I was hoping to see a dynamic object, like the `Query` or the `Form` so I could use dynamic property names, something like this:

```
CommonName = Request.Headers.cn;
Email = Request.Headers.mail;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Since `Request.Headers["cn"]` returns a string, using `.FirstOrDefault()` on it will only return the first letter of that string...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The headers is set up this way to give better strong typing support for the common headers; if you're using non-standard headers you'll get slightly uglier syntax unless you write you own wrapper around them.